# Internet connectivity lost every 10-15 minutes (ethernet cable)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ethernet, dhcp, connectivity

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, and I connect to my router using a LAN cable. The connection interface is called enp2s0.
The router gives IP through DHCP to me. Everything works fine, for 10-15 minutes, and then internet is disconnected.
By disconnected I mean the websites are stuck at "Resolving Host..." or "Connecting...", even though the ubuntu top bar doesn't show disconnection (i.e. shows that I'm connected via Wired Network, nothing changes there).

I then try to ping my gateway (192.168.1.1), and it returns Destination Host Unreachable.

At the time at which this happens, the syslog shows nothing noticeable which can be related to this.

Now If I fiddle a bit, disconnect my LAN cable and connect it back, wait a few minutes, I get reconnected again.

What information is needed so this can be debugged further? The problem has recently started, and wasn't there before.

Comment: Try a different cable if you believe that fiddling with it resolves the problem.

Comment: Besides trying a different cable, install and use ethtool, very handy.

Comment: Probably fiddling is wrong word.. I just pull it out, wait until unix recognizes disconnection, then put it back in... and hope for a connection.

Comment: @DrEval got ethtool installed, but how to utilize it in this situation?

Comment: I suggest asking @RuiFRibeiro

Comment: `ethtool eth0` or whatever the name of the ethernet interface

Comment: Does restarting the network-manager service solve the problem?